# How to start single Spring Boot Microservice on Multiple Ports in STS/eclipse?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

How  to start single Spring Boot Microservice on Multiple Ports in STS/eclipse ?

Comment: What is the context? Are you talking about starting the service with a IDE, in a container, via the command line,... Please give more information..

Comment: @gWom Yes .. It is for IDE only

Comment: see [Tried to add a self-answered wiki-post, but just got downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251878/839601)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start a single microservice on multiple ports.
    Steps are below.

```
1. Right click on     project -> Run As.. -> Run Configuration.
```

2.Create New Boot App configuration. 
In Environment tab add "Server.port =9090" (** Use any port you like and available :) ). 
Apply and Run. 
This will execute same microservice on same port .
    For more use above steps 1 & 2.

```
Danke,
Rahul
```

[image]